# Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире после слова "передача"?

Лучшая передача та, в которой меньше трения.

Answer (score 2):

Даже и не факультативно. Просто нет смысла ставить тире.

Comment: А, к примеру, здесь:

"Самая лучшая передача (?) та, в которой меньше трения"?

Comment: Слава, а зачем здесь тире? Ни под одно известный пункт (употребление тире) это предложение не подходит. Ср.: Он тот, кого я видел на вокзале. 
Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей связки ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа. Здесь ск-ое - местоимение.

Comment: Я же говорил: тире факультативно.

Ведь если ставить ударение в подобных предложениях не на местоимении "та", а на слове "лучшая", какие же могут быть возражения против тире? 

ПРИМЕР:

"У всякого истинного писателя САМАЯ ЛУЧШАЯ книга — та, что ещё не написана".

https://books.google.ru/books?id=z3AjAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B0%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B0%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=niElVZmkM4PVygOa_4KABQ&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, тире здесь факультативно.

Прочитаете с паузой перед "та" -- поставьте;  без паузы -- не ставьте.